# How to Detect dragging in my mapView which is in a fragment controlled by tabHost?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-tabhost

As described, i have a mapView in one of the fragments that are controlled by tabhost. I tried to set an onDragListener for my mapView so i can disable the parent's scrollview whenever user tries to drag the map but the listener won't fire.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

There are few additional things that you have to Implement.

1) Create wrapper class:

```
public class MapWrapperLayout extends FrameLayout {

    public interface OnDragListener {
        public void onDrag(MotionEvent motionEvent);
    }

    private OnDragListener mOnDragListener;

    public MapWrapperLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (mOnDragListener != null) {
            mOnDragListener.onDrag(ev);
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public void setOnDragListener(OnDragListener mOnDragListener) {
        this.mOnDragListener = mOnDragListener;
    }
}
```

2) Create subclass of MapFragment class:

```
public class CustomMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    private View mOriginalView;
    private MapWrapperLayout mMapWrapperLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mOriginalView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        mMapWrapperLayout = new MapWrapperLayout(getActivity());
        mMapWrapperLayout.addView(mOriginalView);

        return mMapWrapperLayout;
}

    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return mOriginalView;
    }

    public void setOnDragListener(MapWrapperLayout.OnDragListener onDragListener) {
        mMapWrapperLayout.setOnDragListener(onDragListener);
    }
```

3) In you Activity make use of the CustomMapFragment:

```
  // Google map init block
    CustomMapFragment customMapFragment = ((CustomMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    customMapFragment.setOnDragListener(new MapWrapperLayout.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrag(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.d("ON_DRAG", String.format("ME: %s", motionEvent));
            // Handle motion event:
        }
    });
    GoogleMap map = customMapFragment.getMap();
```

4) Finally, the Layout would go as:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="your.package.CustomMapFragment"/>
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: i dont think i can do so with tabhost. How do i incoporate this with tabhost?